How to remove specific displayed product category from WooCommerce loop
I am creating a plugin and, if the user is not logged in, I need to exclude a product category and its children from WooCommerce loop and from the search too.
I am displaying the product categories and the products in the catalog.
By now, I'm using the following code and works fine to hide the products of a category:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'exclude_specific_product_category_query', 10, 2 );

function exclude_specific_product_category_query( $tax_query) {

  if( !is_user_logged_in()){
    
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; 

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array(48),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    );

  }

  return $tax_query;
    
}

But the category is still visible in the loop of categories.
When i'm logged in, the product and the categories still visible.
logged in
When i'm not logged in, the product has been excluded but the categories still visible.
Not logged in
The product "Teste" and the other categories (THC Isolado, THC Isolado, THC Full Spectrum, THC Full Spectrum) belong to the category with the term_id 48.
What can I do to exclude a category and its products from the all site?
